# Why did Mount Fuji (富士山) become "Fujiyama" in English?

Tags: translation, nuances, names

If we look at the Japanese word, there is no "Fujiyama" at all. I have a hunch that this was a mistake of a translator who transliterated 富士山 wrongly due to the kanji "yama" reading. Yet if it's a mistake, why was it so widely spreaded? Wikipedia refers to "Fujiyama" as a disambiguation to "Mount Fuji" and I even saw a Japanese book with the title "FUJIYAMA". Was it really someone's mistake or Japanese has some variation about this particular mountain?

For example, here in Russia many people consider "Fujiyama" normal name where those who study Japanese consider it as a terrible inaccuracy of a translator. Where is the truth?

Comment: We do say ふじのやま as well if not ふじやま.

Comment: I have never heard ふじのやま, thank you! But the mystery is _who_ and _why_ translated Mountain Fuji as one word "Fujiyama".. and, more importantly, _why_ did this name become so popular and there was nobody to "fix" it...

Comment: Are you sure this is true? I've never heard it as "Fujiyama" in English. It was probably the same kind of mistake that allowed the translation of "Kamikaze" as "Kamikaze" as opposed to しんぷう (the reading "kamikaze" has since been backwards-imported into Japan). I think this question is too subjective to be a real question unless we can know this isn't the mistake of one Russian translator who subsequently influenced a bunch of people to make the same mistake.

Comment: I've never heard Fujiyama either, but if I do I'll ask them say "とみさむらいやま" instead.

Comment: To me, "Fujiyama" is the name of [a roller coaster](https://www.fujiq.jp/attraction/fujiyama.html) (which is, "American mountains"? :D).

Comment: I'm voting to migrate it to the English Stackexchange.

Comment: I've definitely hear Fujiyama in UK TV shows on Japan. The mistake has propagated well beyond Russia.

Comment: @brokenheadphones yes! Fujiyama is an amazing roller coaster at fujiQ. I went 2 years ago. Not to mention the beautiful sight of the actual mountain while riding the coaster :)   ... as for the question, I have never heard of Fujiyama referring to the mountain before. They say mount Fuji in French, and I assumed in English too.

Comment: I think the question could be rephrased to ask about the validity of the reading *fujiyama* for 富士山 in Japanese and leave all speculations about why and how this became a "thing" in English to a separate question elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

There is a famous phrase "fujiyama, geisha" = "富{ふ}士{じ}山{やま}、芸者{げいしゃ}." This phrase as the symbol of Japan is believd spoken by foreigners during the Meiji Period.
It could be a likely tale.

We Japanese have accepted "Fuji-yama" as "外{がい}人{じん}のちょっと変{へん}な日本語."

Comment: `外人のちょっと変な英語` <- 「英語」なんですか。「ちょっと変な日本語」ではなく？

Comment: Shoko-san, 確かにそうでした。